# Apache2 não está aceitando método de requisição PUT

Tags: php, linux, apache, http-métodos

Tentei fazer uma requisição do tipo `PUT` em um projeto meu, porém está sendo retornado o seguinte erro:

> The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /index.php

Estou usando o PHP para fazer essa requisição, mas especificamente usando o framework Laravel 5.

Pelo que pude perceber isso parecer ser um problema do apache, e não do framework que eu estou usando, uma vez que a página de erro do Laravel é bem diferente da página do Apache2.

Essa página, ao que tudo indica, deve ser retornada pelo Apache:

[image: Método not Allowed - Apache2]

Nunca passei por esse problema antes.

Por gentileza, alguém poderia me informar se é necessário configurar o  apache para resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei explicar ao certo o que ocasionou o problema, mas consegui resolver agora esse problema simplesmente instalando o `libapache2-mod-php5`.

Veja:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Agora está funcionando corretamente.

**Observação**:  Não precisei configurar o `<limit />`

Referência:

- [Server Fault - Apache2 and PHP5: Module or Filter](https://serverfault.com/a/341877)

Parece que o problema estava relacionado ao `libapache2-mod-php5filter` que estava instalado. Ao instalar o libapache2-mod-php5, ele removeu o módulo anterior.